# Reading objects from file after dumping then to file

Tags: python, pickle

I've made a function to write objects to a file:

```
def StoreToFile(Thefile,objekt):
    utfil=None
    utfil=open(Thefile,'wb')
    pickle.dump(objekt,utfil)
    return True
    if utfil is not None:
    utfil.close()
```

And my code to use this function:

```
for st in Stadion:
    StoreToFile(r'C:\pytest\prod.psr',st)
```

This works like a charm, but how can I put the objects back to a list object?

I have the code to extract the objects, but I'm unable to see how I can iterate through the objects to put them in a new list.
So far I have this:

```
def ReadFromFile(filename):
    infile=None
    infile=open(filename,'rb')
    objekt=pickle.load(infile)
```

Comment: Some coding advice: Note that the `utfil/infile = None` lines are completely useless, because their value is overwritten in the following lines.  Note also that the two lines after `return True` are also never used, since the function returns before executing them.  Also note that PEP 8 recommends that you use a space after the comma, in argument lists: `dump(object, utfil)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for st in Stadion:
    StoreToFile(r'C:\pytest\prod.psr',st)
```

> This works like a charm.

If you mean "run without errors", then yes, it does "work". This code repeatedly overwrites the file, so it will only contain the last item in the list.

Use this instead:

```
StoreToFile(r'C:\pytest\prod.psr', Stadion)
```

Your `ReadFromFile()` function should work just fine as it is and return a list (assuming above fix).

Also not sure what this does:

```
return True
if Thefile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I changed the code to your suggestion, but have some isses with the ReadFromFile. If I try list=Readfromfile(filename) this should update the list, or a new list with the items in the file, but instead i get an error. It seems like it's unable to write the result back.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is silly the `utfil = None` business doesn't make sense, because the only way `open(...)` can fail is with an exception, in which case the rest of the function won't be executed anyway. The right way to do this is with a *context manager*: the `with` statement.

Instead, do:

```
def storeToFile(path, o):
    try:
        with open(path, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(o, f)
            return True
    except pickle.PicklingError, IOError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just pickle the whole list.

Comment: How, do you mean? I'm new to Pickle

Comment: Another answer explains more clearly.  Pass the whole list to StoreToFile rather than separately storing each item.

Comment: Something like': newlist=pickle.load(pickledFile) ?

Answer (score 0):

To pickle the objects to the same file, use this function:

```
def storeToFile(fileName, o):
    try:
        with open(fileName, "a") as file:
            cPickle.dump(o, file)
            return True
    except pickle.PicklingError, IOError:
        return False
```

Note that the file is opened with mode `"a"`, so that new data is appended to the end.

To load the objects again, use this:

```
def loadEntireFile(fileName):
    try:
        with open(fileName) as file:
            unpickler = cPickle.Unpickler(file)
            while True:
                yield unpickler.load()
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

This function tries to load objects from the file until it encounters `EOF`, which is indicated by an [`EOFError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError). You can use it like this:

```
foo = [str(x) for x in range(10)]
for x in foo:
    storeToFile("test.pickle", x)

foo2 = list(load("test.pickle"))
```

The [`list`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) function takes any [iterable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable) and builds a list from it. The function `loadEntireFile` contains a [`yield`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) statement, making it a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators), so it can be passed to any function taking an iterable.